# Search a string in .txt using power shell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to search a string in a text file.
The text is

> %oracle_home%\perl\bin.

I am using powershell command

```
select-string c:\OraEnviromentCheck.txt -pattern -match "%ORACLE_HOME%\perl\bin" -Quiet > c:\result1.txt
```

I am unable to understand why this isn't working.
Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Double your "\": i.e. your pattern should be %ORACLE_HOME%\\perl\\bin

Comment: In addition to right @DavidBrabant's hint: `select-string` does not accept parameter `-match`. Instead of  doubling "\" backslashes you could use `-SimpleMatch`.

Comment: @DavidBrabant thanks what you suggested worked. Ran this select-string c:\OraEnviromentCheck.txt -pattern "%ORACLE_HOME\%\\perl\\bin" -Quiet > c:\POWERSHELLRESULT.txt.